# Return the most common element as a string not a list python

Tags: python, list

I know I can use the `counter` from `collections` to return the most common elements in an array or a string and so on. However this counter returns a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. Lets say I want to find most common characters in a string using counter:

```
Counter('abracadabra').most_common(1)
```

This will however return an answer of type **list** like this:

```
[('a', 5)]
```

Is there a way to return only the character "a" as a type of **string** without the times it is repeated?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just grabbing the string from the output of Counter.most_common()?

something like:

```
Counter('abracadabra').most_common(1)[0][0]
```